# Validate data before double way binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How to validate data when the value is changed in the view (using Angular) and execute the watchers only once the data has being validated. Please share you idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the html,

```
    <div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyApp">
        <div ng-if="this_is == 'me'">
                   {{this_is}}
        </div>
    <div ng-if="this_is == 'you'">
               {{this_is_not}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the angularjs controller,
application name 'MyApp'
controller name 'MyApp'

```
$scope.this_is = 'me';
$scope.this_is_not = 'stranger';
```

or

```
   $scope.this_is = 'you';
   $scope.this_is_not = 'stranger';
```

and if we another scenario,

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyApp">
{{this_is}}
</div>
</div>
```

and in the angular controller,

```
if(myvar=='me'){
 $scope.this_is = "me";
}else{
 $scope.this_is = "stranger";
}
```